# Semaphore and father son process

Tags: c, semaphore

I have this code that creates a process & his son , each one of them will make a " for loop " in his code , which will write in a file from a to z and from A to Z ; with the use of only one semaphore the file created contatins only capital letters from " A " to " Z " and one " a " which means only the father completed his loop while the son managed to run only one time.

With the use of two semaphores i managed to run the code like i wanted it to AaBbCcDdEeFf...Zz

So my question is about the following code( with one semaphore ), why does the son not complete his loop ?

Thank you for your help

Edit : clef = key in the code

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/sem.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>

 main()
{
                int pid_P2,clef,sema;
                char i;
                ushort tab_sema[1];
                struct sembuf operation [1];

                FILE *p ;
                p=fopen("file.txt","w");
                if (p==NULL)
                {
                 perror("Error opening file");
                 exit(0);
                }

                clef=ftok("file.txt",8);

                operation[0].sem_num=0;
                operation[0].sem_flg=0;

                pid_P2=fork();

                sema=semget(clef,1,IPC_CREAT|0600);
                if (sema==-1)                {                perror("pb semget");
                                                               exit(0);                }

                semctl(sema,0,SETVAL,1);

                if (pid_P2==0)
                {                          /* Son's Code */
                  for (i='a';i<'z'+1;i++) 
                   {
                    operation[0].sem_op=-1;

                    semop(sema,operation,1);

                    fprintf(p,"%c",i);

                    fflush(p); 
                    operation[0].sem_op=+1;               

                    semop(sema,operation,1);


                    }
                    exit(0);
                 }

                 else{                /* Father's Code */

                 for (i='A';i<'Z'+1;i++) 
                  {
                   operation[0].sem_op=-1;
                   semop(sema,operation,1);

                   fprintf(p,"%c",i);
                   fflush(p);
                   operation[0].sem_op=+1;

                   semop(sema,operation,1);

                  }

                  sleep(2);
                  exit(0);
                 }
                fclose(p);             
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested you code and I had

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

thus I cannot reproduce your problem.

Nevertheless seem to me that you problem comes from the fact that your father process doesn't wait for completion of its child: you should replace `sleep(2)` by `waitpid(pid_P2, NULL, 0)` to make sure you doesn't exit before the child finished its job.

That said, your semaphore seem to be used more like a mutex that a signaling semaphore, thus there is a race between the father and the child for the access of the file. It seems that the father always win in your case and exits before the son had time to write more than 'a'. Thus I think you won't be able to achieve your AaBbCcDdEeFf...Zz goal using a single semaphore.

Comment: Thank you for the reply , i don't understand why you couldn't reproduce the problem since i tried it on different machines and had the same problem but anyway i understand my error i will try using waitpid and see if it works , thank you again !

Comment: I Found my problem , the code i posted had the " exit(0); " in the son process outside the code instructions which made the execution like you said "ABC...Zabcd...z " , and my code had the "exit(0) ;" inside the son's code which made him exit the loop and thus exit the son's code !